# Decimal Point Vertical Justification

Tags: r

Is there a way to change the (output) decimal point vertical justification in R from low to centred ?

MWE:

```
x <- 15.566667
round(x, digits = 2)

# [1] 15.57
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the use case for this? Are you trying to change this for display in a graph?

Comment: @MikeH. I also think this is an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Mike H. Yes I am (for a very fussy Journal). The answer below does works for me if I set `axes = FALSE` in `plot()` and create my own axis using `axis()` with numeric labels. Sorry for omitting the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this to set the appropriate option `options(OutDec= "·")`

Comment: oh this is great to make jokes to work colleagues. `options(OutDec= "5")`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the global options you can always use `gsub` as well:

```
gsub("\\.","·",round(x, digits = 2))
[1] "15·57"
```

Note the drawback to this is that it converts it to character.

---

Another way using `gsub` and `Unicode` characters would be:

```
y <- gsub("\\.","\U00B7",round(x, digits = 2))
Encoding(y) <- "UTF-8"

y
[1] "15·57"
```

This way gives you a lot of flexibility of what symbol you want (instead of having to copy/paste it) and again doesn't require global options

Comment: @ Mike H. Probably a wise thing to do. TYVM.

Comment: No problem. Yea I prefer not messing with global options